# Permutation and combination formation of numbers

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways we can make 5 digit number out of 0,1,2,3,4,7,8 such that it is divisible by 3

Comment: Hello amol shrivastava, welcome at MSE! Since it is your first question, you probably don't know that it is better, usually, to give within your questions, what you have already tried, what you don't understand, etc... If not, people get the impression that you are making them doing your own homework...

Answer (score 2):

We observe the remainders given by $0,1,2,3,4,7,8$ when divided by $3$ is $0,1,-1,0,1,1,-1$.

The **Rule of divisiblity by 3 is sum of digits is divisible by 3**, so permutations should be such that remainders add upto $0 $  or $3$.

- Remainders adding upto 0

  - case 1: $(0,1,1,-1,-1)$ the permutations that give these set of remainders are $(0,1,4,2,8),(0,1,7,2,8),(0,7,4,2,8),(3,1,4,2,8),(3,1,7,2,8),(3,7,4,2,8)$
  - case 2: $(0,0,1,1,1)$ the permutations that give these set of remainders are $(0,3,1,4,7)$
- Hence 4 cases that contain one zero can be written as 5 digit numbers in $4\cdot 4!$ AND other 3 cases which have all non zero distinct numbers can be written as 5 digit numbers in $5!$ ways. $$\text{Multiples of 3} = 4\cdot 4 \cdot 4!+3\cdot 5!=744$$